# Why my css files import does not working?

Tags: html, css, icons, materialize

i am importing matirialize css files into my code. i have copied to code from the link and created css files in my code and imported them like the code below, these are the imports: (i dont want to import from the internet because i want the project to work without internet either.)

```
    <script src = "jquery.js"></script>
    <script src = "Sources/Chart.js"></script>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href = "Sources/bootstrap.css">
    <script src = "client.js"></script>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href = "Sources/MatirialIcons.css">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href = "Sources/Matirialize.css">
    <script type = "text/javascript"
            src = "Sources/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src = "Sources/Matirialize.js"></script>
```

and its showing me in the html page, like the image below, instead of showing the matirialize icons
[image]

Comment: Did you import the font as well ?

Comment: when i imported from the internet with links, it worked fine. but when i changed from internet links to css files in my project this is what it does

Comment: Check css file path try to open in browser window.

Comment: look in F12 (develop tool) if files were loaded

Comment: and also as I see in documention they  use `.min` files:https://materializecss.com/getting-started.html

Comment: i just saw now there is a font link in the matirializeIcon file, that is imported like this: src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v41/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2) format('woff2'); and i tried to import it without the url but it does not working

Comment: You also need the Material-Icons font to make it works, by either downloading the font and importing it in your css or using a link in the `head` of your HTML.

Comment: do you download the files of the font?

Comment: לבני מלכה,  i have the following code in the css matirializeIcon file which is a link aswell: src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v41/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2) format('woff2'); 
but i dont want to use it as a link because i dont want to be need to use internet. how do i import this file in the css file without using the url() command?

Comment: yes i downloaded the font file and put it in the Sources Directory but it doesn't let me import the file from there instead of the url command

Comment: @YoavLinder Check [@font-face](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face)

Comment: just checked, how can i know the font name of the file i downloaded? its name is flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2

Comment: You don't need to know the name, you can define it with `font-family`

Answer (score 3):

If it's a problem with the font you should define the font-family just like @Arkellys said.

here are the steps to do that:

**Step-1:** convert the downloaded font https://web-font-generator.com/

**Step-2:** Download the generated font

**Step-3:** Open font directory (font/font-name) and include the downloaded fonts in it

**Step-4:** include font-face in the stylesheet

**Step-5:** call the stylesheet

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'fontName';
    src: url('../fonts/fontName/fontName.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('../fonts/fontName/fontName.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('../fonts/fontName/fontName.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
         url('../fonts/fontName/fontName.ttf')  format('truetype') /* Safari, Android, iOS */

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

i found a solution:
in the matirialize icon file, there is the font file import
(this is the matirialize icon css file):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Material Icons'), local('MaterialIcons-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v22/2fcrYFNaTjcS6g4U3t-Y5ZjZjT5FdEJ140U2DJYC3mY.woff2) format('woff2');
}

.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: normal;
  direction: ltr;
  -moz-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

all need is to open the url and download the file, put it in the project and then change the upper code to:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Material Icons';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url(iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.eot); /* For IE6-8 */
    src: local('Material Icons'),
    local('MaterialIcons-Regular'),
        /* Old file: url(iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2) format('woff2'), */
        /* load new file */

    url(flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2) format('woff2'),
    url(iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```